# How to sum values of duplicated records in Excel?

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, sum, unique

I have the following problem:

[image: Description]

I will appreciate any help and suggestion on that.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with:

```
=IF(AE2,SUMIF($AD$2:AD2,AD2,$AF$2:AF2),"")
```

Placed in Column AF for example.

If you don't really need that helper column (AE), then you can consolidate it to:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($AD$2:AD2,AD2)>2,SUMIF($AD$2:AD2,AD2,$AF$2:AF2),"")
```

[image]